# Get Jamfile path

Tags: bjam, b2

I am currently defining a constant in order to use it within a function in my Jamfile:

project-root.jam

```
path-constant LIB_PATH : ./x_my_lib/ ;
```

myjamfile.jam

```
actions create-build-info.unix
{
        printf "Generating build-info, please wait...\n" ;
        "$(LIB_PATH)/prebuild.sh" $(PROJECT_ROOT) > $(1)
}
```

Would it be possible for the Jamfile to detect what path is located so I don't need to define LIB_PATH as a constant somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you can just use some bash scripting with Bjam :)

```
actions create-build-info.unix
{
    printf "Generating build-info, please wait...\n" ;
    find $(PROJECT_ROOT) -type f -name prebuild.py  -exec {} $(PROJECT_ROOT) \;   > $(1)
}
```